# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on DRF, but when I'm about to run "migrate" for the database, i get
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'.

As PyCharm hints, the same also applies to django_summernote and djoser I have there.
I know there are some threads like this, but nothing from those seems to help - the Python console DOES recognize these modules, and they are added through INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'kursovik.apps.KursovikConfig',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'django_summernote',
'djoser',
'kursovik']
```

I recently downloaded these through

```
pip install djangorestframework
pip install djoser
pip install django-summernote
```

do i need to reinstall them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ensure that your PyCharm console uses the correct Python Path where the packages are available basically so to say.

Go to `File/Settings/YourProject` and check for the following:

[image]

Set the correct path to make the packages available for interpretation procedures.

Comment: OR, you need to make sure you're in your VENV. (Virtual Environment.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already install restframework but still encounter this issue, try this method, this is to install rest in you venv
In your project folder (by sys.executable to find)
In command line：
1）source bin/activate
(then start to install rest framework)
2）pip install djangorestframework
3）deactive
then restart pycharm.