# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'praw'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a website with Django that can get Reddit user's data with a module called PRAW

In my views.py for the app called Data, I tried to import PRAW and do things with it and template things with Django.

I am using PyCharm, so the module PRAW has already been installed in my VirtualEnv. There were no errors importing PRAW in the file alone as well. (I ran the file directly in PyCharm and no error showed up)

However, when I run the server, I get: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'praw'`

Imports made in `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import praw
```

Something wrong happens with the `import praw` statement when server is ran for some reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your virtual environment is active? The reason could either be that you don't have an active virtual environment in which the module `praw` has been installed or  the module has not been installed at all.

Comment: please see my previous answer regarding PyCharm Modules here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62486199/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-rest-framework/62486412#62486412

Comment: I have already installed the praw module, checked my venv and its there; PyCharm also says its there. However, what do you mean by active virtual environment though?

Comment: Did you added installed_apps? maybe u must did it

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd in venv directory.
activate virtual env "Scripts\activate"
install praw "pip install praw"
it shouldnt show the error msg now, even though it might marked with red line in pycharm just run your script ftom cmd with "python filename.py"